# Testcontainers : communicating between different networks

Tags: testcontainers

I am trying to build tests with containers on separated networks, but that can communicate with each other.

The test is built with :

- A "server" network with two containers (postgres, api server)
- A "client" network with one container (other api server)

The tests will call the "other api server", but the "other api server" can't communicate with the "first api server" yet... (Connection refused)

How can I get the good "host:port" I should give to "other api server" to access "first api server" ?

Comment: Is it really important for the test case to use different networks?

Comment: Goal is to mimic real servers architecture (different kubernetes clusters/namespaces), to have a complete infrastructure, and make complete integration tests. I don't know what can be the side-effects of some containers that works as clusters (like zookeeper) if they run on same network but should not be on the same cluster...